# Rails has_one and belongs_to help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to, has-one

I have two models: User and Store

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :store

Schema looks like this:

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.boolean  "admin",              :default => false
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "billing_id"
  end

create_table "stores", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "store_name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

User must login in order to sign up a store by inputting "email" and "store_name". create from stores_controller looks like this:

```
def create

  @store = Store.new(params[:store])
  if @store.save
    @store.user_id = current_user.id 
    flash[:success] = "this store has been created"
    redirect_to @store
  else
    @title = "store sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

In ApplicationsController

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```

However, when I check in the database, @store.user_id = nil. For some reason, it's not able to put in current_user.id into @store.user_id. Anybody able to help in detecting why this might be? I thought I had associations correctly implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're setting the `@store.user_id` AFTER saving it.

Ideally, you should be using the association builder for this:

```
def new
  @store = @current_user.store.build(params[:store])
```

More information about these can be found in the ["Association Basics"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/assoication_basics.html) guide.